# How do I write a Unicode string to the console screen buffer?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe, windows-console

Given a *handle* (hStdOut here) to the *standard output device*, I use the following 2 procedures to write an arbitrary string from a console application:

**Excerpt:**

```
procedure Send(const s: string);
var
  len: cardinal;
begin
  len:=Length(s);
  WriteFile(hStdOut,s[1],len,len,nil);
end;

procedure SendLn(const s: string);
begin
  Send(s + #13#10);
end;
```

**My trouble:**

This statement doesn't render correctely the string as I expected:

```
SendLn('The harder they come...');
```

**My Question:**

Is there a "WideString" overload of `WriteFile` or should I consider another Unicode-aware function that access the console screen buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you need to specify the length in *bytes* rather than *characters*. So use [`ByteLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ByteLength) rather than `Length`. At the moment what you are passing in `len` is half the byte size of the buffer.

I also believe that you should not use the same variable for the `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` and `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` parameters.

```
procedure Send(const s: string);
var
  NumberOfBytesToWrite, NumberOfBytesWritten: DWORD;
begin
  NumberOfBytesToWrite := ByteLength(s);
  if NumberOfBytesToWrite>0 then
    WriteFile(hStdOut, s[1], NumberOfBytesToWrite, NumberOfBytesWritten, nil);
end;
```

The above is fine if your `stdout` is expecting UTF-16 encoded text. If not, and if it is expecting ANSI text then you should switch to AnsiString.

```
procedure Send(const s: AnsiString);
var
  NumberOfBytesToWrite, NumberOfBytesWritten: DWORD;
begin
  NumberOfBytesToWrite := ByteLength(s);
  if NumberOfBytesToWrite>0 then
    WriteFile(hStdOut, s[1], NumberOfBytesToWrite, NumberOfBytesWritten, nil);
end;
```

Exactly what you need to send to the standard output device depends on what text encoding it is expecting and I don't know that.

Finally, if this is a console that you are writing to then you should simply use [`WriteConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for answering. The length issue is addressed by using ByteLength but I am still in trouble: Every character of the string is rendered with an additional space character.

Comment: @menjaraz Yes, that's because your stdout device is expecting ANSI I think. Try the second chunk of code in the answer. Do you have any more information for us about what type of output devices you are working with.

Comment: WriteConsole does exactly what I am expecting. Thank you.