# GotoXY implementation

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe, windows-console

This question is a follow-up one to my prior post entitled [How to fix this procedure writing a string to the console screen buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946039/how-to-fix-this-procedure-writing-a-string-to-the-console-screen-buffer).

I want to set the cursor to a given (x,y) position prior to writing an arbitrary string:

```
GotoXY(x,y)
SendLn('The harder they come...');
```

How can be `procedure GotoXY(x, y: integer)` implemented ?

Comment: The question is why you are using [`WriteFile`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946039/how-to-fix-this-procedure-writing-a-string-to-the-console-screen-buffer) to write to the console. Use the console APIs, e.g. `WriteConsole` and friends.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you:   len:=Length(s);
  WriteConsole(hStdOut, @s[1],len,len,nil); does the job.

Comment: Remember that if stdout is redirected to a file then WriteConsole will fail.

Comment: Fortunately, it's not part of my requirement.

Comment: Or even easier, get [JEDI](http://delphi-jedi.org) JCLs `JCLConsole`, and use the `JCLScreenBuffer.Write(Text, X, Y, Attributes)` method. :) `Attributes` defaults to nil, so you can exclude it to use the default text and background colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google reveals

[SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you pointing it to me. Indeed, there is a reference to it in the **Windows.pas** unit and I miss it.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this is my solution to the question, based on JamesB's post (the accepted answer):

```
procedure GotoXY(x, y: Integer);
var
  CursorCoord: _COORD;
begin
  CursorCoord.x := x;
  CursorCoord.y := y;

  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, CursorCoord);
end;
```

**Edit:**

The [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) refered by jamesB above also points to another interesting related resource, namely [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Getting the *column and row coordinates of the cursor in the console screen buffer* is also part of my requirements.

Here are the 2 Delphi functions I've written based on the cited resource:

```
var
  Buffer: _Console_Screen_Buffer_Info;

...

function WhereX: Integer;
begin
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut,Buffer);
  //
  Result:=Buffer.dwCursorPosition.X;
end;

function WhereY: Integer;
begin
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut,Buffer);
  //
  Result:=Buffer.dwCursorPosition.Y;
end;
```